# Image not displaying in email body

Tags: android

I am trying to display an image in an email body but however it is not displaying.

here is my code i am using:

```
    messageIntent.setType("text/html");
    messageIntent.setType("application/image");
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/www/img/logo2.png"));
```

Everything else is displaying correctly but the image isn't displaying.

Could some one please help?

Thanks